# Wordpress the_content() not showing after the portfolio section

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a custom template for the homepage. I want to call the content after the portfolio, but it doesn't work.  I can't find where I made a mistake. It works when I call above the portfolio. Anyone know how I could accomplish this?

```html
<section id="portfolio" class="portfolio atop">

  <!-- Portfolio Filter -->
  <div class="portfolio_filter">

    <ul>
      <?php $categories = get_categories("taxonomy=categories");
      foreach ($categories as $category) : echo '<li><a data-filter=".' . $category->slug . '"  href="#">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
      endforeach; ?>
      <li><a class="select-cat" data-filter="*" href="#">All Works</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row masonry clearfix">
      <!-- a work -->
      <?php $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'orderby'   => 'date',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
      );

      $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
      while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php $portcolor = get_field('text_color_of_featured_image'); ?>
        <?php $taxonomy = 'categories';
        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'categories'); ?>
        <?php foreach ($terms as $term)  ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_html(get_permalink()); ?>" class="col-xl-4 col-md-6 grid-item <?php echo esc_html($term->slug); ?> <?php echo esc_attr($portcolor); ?>" data-type="ajax-load">
          <figure class="portfolio-item <?php $portfolio_type = get_field('portfolio_type');
                                        echo esc_attr($portfolio_type); ?>">
            <div class="image">
              <?php $featured_image = get_field('portfolio_featured_image'); ?>
              <img src="<?php echo esc_url($featured_image['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($featured_image['alt']); ?>" />
            </div>

            <figcaption>
              <span><?php echo esc_html($term->name); ?></span>
              <h3 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </a>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- container end -->
</section>

 <?php the_content(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the global post after your custom `WP_Query` with `wp_reset_postdata()`. See below:

```
<section id="portfolio" class="portfolio atop">

  <!-- Portfolio Filter -->
  <div class="portfolio_filter">

    <ul>
      <?php $categories = get_categories("taxonomy=categories");
      foreach ($categories as $category) : echo '<li><a data-filter=".' . $category->slug . '"  href="#">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
      endforeach; ?>
      <li><a class="select-cat" data-filter="*" href="#">All Works</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row masonry clearfix">
      <!-- a work -->
      <?php $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'orderby'   => 'date',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
      );

      $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
      while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php $portcolor = get_field('text_color_of_featured_image'); ?>
        <?php $taxonomy = 'categories';
        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'categories'); ?>
        <?php foreach ($terms as $term)  ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_html(get_permalink()); ?>" class="col-xl-4 col-md-6 grid-item <?php echo esc_html($term->slug); ?> <?php echo esc_attr($portcolor); ?>" data-type="ajax-load">
          <figure class="portfolio-item <?php $portfolio_type = get_field('portfolio_type');
                                        echo esc_attr($portfolio_type); ?>">
            <div class="image">
              <?php $featured_image = get_field('portfolio_featured_image'); ?>
              <img src="<?php echo esc_url($featured_image['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($featured_image['alt']); ?>" />
            </div>

            <figcaption>
              <span><?php echo esc_html($term->name); ?></span>
              <h3 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </a>
      <?php endwhile; 
      // reset global post data
      wp_reset_postdata();?>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- container end -->
</section>

<?php the_content(); ?>
```